# rails infinite scroll repeating contents

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, infinite-scroll

I am not sure what I am missing here. I Have implemented infinite scroll on a page, but the results are being repeated more than once. I created a list of items for my dev envrionment which are made sequentially. They are being repeated in the infinite scroll eg. item no 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 46, 45, 44, 46, 45, 44, 43, .....

index.js.erb

```
   $('#my-posts').append('<%= j render @news %>');
   <% if @news.next_page %>
   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @news %>');
    <% else %>
   $(window).off('scroll');
   $('.pagination').remove();
   <% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<section class='page-content-container'>
 <h2 class='static-page-subheading'>Stay Up to Date</h2>
  <%= render 'news' %>
   <div id="infinite-scrolling">
    <%= will_paginate @news%>
   </div>
 </section>
```

_news.html.erb

```
<div id='my-posts'>
 <% @news.each do |news| %>
  <div class='news-item-container'>
<h2><%= news.title %></h2>
    <h3><%= news.created_at %></h3>
<%= truncate(news.body, :length => 500, escape: false) %>
<%= link_to 'Read More', news %>
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

pagination.js.coffee
(ignore indentation here)

```
 jQuery ->
   if $('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0
     $(window).on 'scroll', ->
       more_news_url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')

       if more_news_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60
         $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />')
         $.getScript more_news_url
         return
       return
```

Comment: no, its just stack overflow. hang on I'll edit

Comment: Can I see your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Just replicated it locally and I remembered I fixed this somehow and now I remember. This is what I did to fix it:

index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "posts" %>
<div class="append-me"></div>

<%= will_paginate @posts, class: 'pagination pagination-sm' %>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('.append-me').append( '<%= j render "posts" %>' );


<% if @posts.next_page %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @posts, class: "pagination pagination-sm" %>');
<% else %>
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

_posts.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="well" style="margin: 15% 0%;">
    <%= post.data %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

post.js

```
if ($('.pagination')) {
         $(window).scroll(function() {
            console.log("sdasd")
            url = $(' .next_page').attr('href');

            // console.log($(window).scrollTop())
            // console.log($(document).height())
            // console.log($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50)
            if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150) {

                $('.pagination').text("Fetching more profiles...");
                $.getScript(url)
            }
            // $(window).scroll();
        });
    }
```

The trick is, I had to be explicit with creating class "pagination" in both my index.html and index.js files. Secondly, I did `<%= j render "posts" %>` for my index.js.erb file rather than `@posts`

Comment: Thanks for your help. However I have copied this exactly and adaopted to 'news' but ti still wont work. I can see in the console the js is working, but there is no infinite scrolling. Is this what you did exactly?

Comment: yeah did you do the classes

Comment: yeah i did, cant fingure it out

Comment: try removing this `$(window).off('scroll');`